# jdbc Mysql connection syntax to use near '?,?,?)'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I really couldn't find why it gives out this error. Some say that its the jdbc-connector version may cause it. But I first want to know if this syntax has an error independent from its version.

Here is my function:

```
public void ogrenci_ekle(String isim, int dnem, int ortalama){
        try {

            String sorgu = "INSERT INTO ogrenciler (isim,dönem,ortalama) VALUES (?,?,?) ";
            PreparedStatement pre_statement = con.prepareStatement(sorgu);
            pre_statement.setString(1, isim);
            pre_statement.setInt(2, dnem);
            pre_statement.setInt(3, ortalama);
            pre_statement.executeUpdate(sorgu);


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("HatA");
            Logger.getLogger(db_test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

And here is the output.

```
Apr 13, 2020 7:36:14 PM app1.db_test ogrenci_ekle
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1335)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
    at app1.db_test.ogrenci_ekle(db_test.java:80)
    at app1.db_test.main(db_test.java:40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `pre_statement.executeUpdate(sorgu);` should be `pre_statement.executeUpdate();`

You are calling [`Statement.executeUpdate(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)), you wanted [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())